# How CCA ( Clear Channel Assessment ) physical carrier sensig is done?

Tags: linux, wifi

I want to know how PHY carrier sensing is done (in detail) and where code for phy sensing is present. Is it in driver or firmware ? I am using atheros pci express, ath9k driver.

Comment: I think you can post your question on the [Linux Wireless Mailing List](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/MailingLists).

Answer (score 1):

To get the physical sensing data back from hardware. there is 1 structure called survey_info which is filled in ath9k driver. function ath_update_survey_stats() reads the values stored in the registers present in PCI card. From there we can get channel busy time.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly performed in the WiFi module's firmware. You probably cannot get your hands on the Atheros firmware source.

Comment: yes you are correct we can not touch firmware, but there is a way to get the physical sensing data back from hardware. there is 1 structure called survey_info which is filled in ath9k driver . function ath_update_survey_stats() reads the values stored in the registers present in PCI card. From there you can get channel busy time.

Comment: @Rafal: Yes, that sounds like a possibility. Have you tried printing out that struct in the atheros driver, to see if it contains what you want?

Comment: @ Bjarke Freund-Hansen: yes i tried and finally got it.

Comment: @Rafal: If you want to be nice to other people (and earn some SO points), post your own answer here and accept it. It is perfectly ok to do. :)

Comment: thanks for the advice,but i am new to stackoverflow and i dont know how to ans my own question thats why i added ans as comment. :p

Comment: @Rafal: Just push the "Add Another Answer" button at the bottom of the page, and provide the answer you found.